Merge 2 ACF Text Fields into one ACF Text Field?
a.) Is it possible to merge two ACF text fields into a 3rd field.
Field1: [acf field = "Video_Poster_Path"] 
Field2: [acf field = "Video_Link"]
Field3: [acf field = "Merged_HTML"]

The 3rd field would look like:
     <video poster="[acf field= "Video_Poster_Path"]"
       controls="controls" controlsList=”nodownload” width="880"">
       <source src="[acf field = "Video_Link"]" type="video/mp4">
     </video>

and b.) how ?
IF this has to be done via a function, what would that function look like ?
While this is not my first rodeo, I am not as up to speed with PHP. It’s been a minute since I last looked at php directly. So…help ?
Oh and I’m working with the free version not the pro.
Thanks In Advance.

It kind of sounds like you want your own shortcode maybe?

That would be nice. I still have to pull that field into the Elementor HTML widget. If it's ONE concatenated field then that makes things easier. As you may know elementor doesn't allow for multiple fields, just one.
